# Modify mesh rendering shader

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I have trouble with my mesh file rendering in gazebo. I generate a obj/mtl file and I want to display it in gazebo.
In gazebo the rendering of my object is not properly done, there is lot of artefact. I can reproduce the same problem in Meshlab by setting the "shading "  in vertice mode. When I change it into Face mode there is no strange rendering anymore.

Is there a way in gazebo to do the same as in Meshlab and for the shading in face rendering instead of Vertice rendering?

Edit:
I add more precision on shading rendering on Meshlab part. Here is an explanation on what are the differences in Meshlab between Vert / face shading mode.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572062/what-does-shading-choice-of-meshlab-actually-do![image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572062/what-does-shading-choice-of-meshlab-actually-do!%5Bimage) description](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16105455916799959.png)

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26395/modify-mesh-rendering-shader/) by [dev4all12358](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40016/dev4all12358/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could try adding something like this to your visual block in your SDF file, it seems like it changes the shader used when rendering the model. Specifically the "shader" block.

```
<material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='pixel'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
</material>
```

---

Originally posted by [AJahueyM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/41190/ajahueym/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dev4all12358](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40016/dev4all12358/) on 2021-01-29**:
Thank you for the answer. I still have the same rendering
He is an example of rendering in gazebo:
[link text](https://ibb.co/qdhbWQf)

It seems, the vertices are not displayed in the right way